# Simple Relational Algebra Query

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, algebra, relational-algebra

I have made two relations with the respectful attributes, TEAM(TeamName,TeamID) and PLAYER(TeamID, PlayerName, PlayerHeight)

I am trying to find all the team names in which ALL the players(of that team) have a height greater than 6feet.

My assumptions are that TeamName and TeamID are related, so say TeamName X has TeamID 1 and PlayerName A,B,C can have PlayerHeight 6,7,8 and TeamID 1. Those are examples!

To my understanding, what i must do is
1. Make a Relation of Players with: project-PlayerHeight, TeamID(PLAYER)
2. Somehow calculate if "for every" separate TeamID ALL the PlayerHeight > 6 return that TeamID
3. I can't figure out the last part, and i know the first two are wrong.

Please help, i am very confused and if explained to me i will learn it correctly. Thank you!

Comment: It is Relational Algebra!

Comment: Sorry bud, removed the tag

Comment: π(teamname) (TEAM |x| (PLAYER - (σ(height<6)PLAYER)) )

Comment: @sqlvogel Simpler:: π(teamname) (TEAM |x| σ(height>=6) PLAYER). These give names of teams with *some* player(s) >= 6';  but the question asks for names of teams with *all* players *greater than* 6'. You meant the subtraction to be *TEAM* minus teams with some player(s) *less than or equal to* 6'.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the team and take only those having no player <= height 6

```
select t.teamname
from team t
join player p on p.teamid = t.teamid
group by t.teamname
having sum(case when p.playerheight <= 6 then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you Juergen! Is there any way you can express this in Relational Algebra?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a new relation between player heights and teams by joining your two existing relations.  In this particular case, however, you don't really need to test that ALL players' heights for a team are greater than the threshold -- you just needs to test that the team's *shortest* player's height surpasses the threshold.  Expressed in SQL, that might look like so:

```
SELECT TeamName, MIN(PLAYER.PlayerHeight) AS MinHeight
FROM TEAM
  JOIN PLAYER
    ON TEAM.TeamID = PLAYER.TeamID
GROUP BY TEAM.TeamName
HAVING MinHeight > 6
```

Comment: I forgot to ask that it be in Relational Algebra format instead of SQL, although it is very helpful for when i design it. Thank you! Might you be able to translate it into RA form?